# Using a complex custom SQL query and returning a queryset in Django 1.7

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I have a slow-running Django ListView on a complaints management app I wrote. It's running slow because, when using the ORM, it doesn't hit the database very efficiently.

I've written the following query, which gets the information I need efficiently:

```
WITH triages AS (
    SELECT
        agreed_resolution_date
        , complaint_id
        , date_completed
        , id
        , stage_id
        , MAX(id) OVER(PARTITION BY complaint_id, stage_id) AS ltst
    FROM complaints_triage
)
SELECT
    cpt.id
    , cplnt.first_name || ' ' || cplnt.last_name AS complainant
    , DATE_PART('year', cs.date_case_received) AS case_year
    , cs.case_reference AS case_reference
    , CASE WHEN cpt.handler_id IS NULL
        THEN NULL
        ELSE usr.first_name || ' ' || usr.last_name
    END AS complaint_handler
    , tm.name AS team
    , stg.stage AS complaint_stage
    , CASE WHEN trg.agreed_resolution_date IS NULL
        THEN ((cpt.date_received + integer '5') - CURRENT_DATE)
        ELSE (trg.agreed_resolution_date - CURRENT_DATE)
    END AS time_left
FROM complaints_complaint AS cpt
INNER JOIN complaints_complainant AS cplnt
    ON cpt.complainant_id = cplnt.id
LEFT JOIN complaints_case AS cs
    ON cpt.case_id = cs.id
LEFT JOIN auth_user AS usr
    ON cpt.handler_id = usr.id
INNER JOIN complaints_stage AS stg
    ON cpt.stage_id = stg.id
INNER JOIN community_team AS tm
    ON cpt.team_id = tm.id
LEFT JOIN triages AS trg
    ON trg.stage_id = cpt.stage_id
    AND trg.complaint_id = cpt.id
    AND trg.id = trg.ltst
WHERE cpt.date_closed IS NULL
ORDER BY time_left
```

I would like to use this query to override `get_queryset` in the `ListView` and use the results as a queryset, with the column headings as the attribute names. But using this query to return results [as described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) returns a list (using `cursor.fetchall`) rather than a queryset. Is there any way to return a queryset from this kind of SQL query? Alternatively, is there another established way to do what I'm trying to?

Comment: But what would this queryset contain? A queryset is a container for model instances, but your query clearly does not map to any particular model class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the idea I was imagining was for it to map to a temporary abstract model, that would be held in memory in order to return the view - analogous to a database view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if that's not possible (which I'm assuming it isn't from your comment :-)), is just using a `TemplateView` and adding the list of tuples from the query as context the best way to go about this?

Comment: You could create an Class that would accept a tuple and map the tuple into the properties. Otherwise the second option you listed is the way you'd have to go. Personally, I think the first option is cleaner and a bit more intuitive. Especially if you have to change the order of the fields in the tuple or make an actual model to replace it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually settled on using a `namedtuple`, which has the great benefit of behaving like a queryset in the template (though obviously without being able to access related items through dot notation). First off I changed my views superclass to `TemplateView` to remove any default queryset. I then defined the following extra context

```
from collections import namedtuple
from django.db import connection

...

class AllLiveComplaintListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'complaints/complaint_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(
            AllLiveComplaintListView,
            self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        with connection.cursor() as c:
            c.execute('''
            # SQL query from question removed for brevity
            ''')
            ComplaintRecord = namedtuple('ComplaintRecord', 'complaint_id, complainant, case_year, case_reference, handler, team, complaint_stage, days_left')
            context['complaint_list'] = map(ComplaintRecord._make, c.fetchall())
        return context
```